# How to put show an outline for each chart series in a RadChart?

Tags: charts, telerik, radchart, uiappearance

I'm trying to customize the appearance of an ASP Web Forms RadChart where the series have `FillType = Solid` while still allowing visibility of the lesser point values behind larger ones. What I really want is each series to have an outline placed on top of all the fills (basically the effect of having a `ChartSeriesType.Line` on top of a `ChartSeriesType.Area`).

I've experimented with setting `LineAppearance.Shadow`, color transparency, and combinations of those but it's still too difficult to discern background series values.

Is there not a simple way to turn on an outline for each series when using a solid fill? OR to set the transparency of the background fill only, not the edges?

[image]

Note the transparency in the above image. I'm afraid allowing more transparency improves the visibility of background values but results in a horrible collection of pastel colors.

Comment: check this section [styling chart elements](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/chart-styling-elements.html).. and this [example](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/chart-building-programmatic-create-complex.html)

Comment: Nice, @NiranjanKala. Applying a border to the series works if I leave color transparency set. Otherwise it gets hidden, too. Not ideal, but getting better. Thx!

Comment: @NiranjanKala thx for the links. I solved my problem and now I owe you some rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to go through `telerik` documentation page [RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX Documentation -Styling Chart Elements](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/chart-styling-elements.html) and this nice example [Creating RadChart Programmatically - more complex example](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/chart-building-programmatic-create-complex.html).

Code snippet:

```
// Define chart and titleRadChart radChart = new RadChart();
radChart.ChartTitle.TextBlock.Text = "My RadChart";
radChart.ChartTitle.TextBlock.Appearance.TextProperties.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
// Define chart series
ChartSeries chartSeries = new ChartSeries();
chartSeries.Appearance.LabelAppearance.Visible = false;
chartSeries.Name = "GDP";
chartSeries.Type = ChartSeriesType.Line;
chartSeries.Appearance.LineSeriesAppearance.Color = System.Drawing.Color.BlueViolet;
// Define the items in the series
chartSeries.AddItem(1);
chartSeries.AddItem(1.5);
chartSeries.AddItem(2.0);
chartSeries.AddItem(2.5);
chartSeries.AddItem(3.5);
// visually enhance the datapoints
chartSeries.Appearance.PointMark.Dimensions.AutoSize = false;
chartSeries.Appearance.PointMark.Dimensions.Width = 5;
chartSeries.Appearance.PointMark.Dimensions.Height = 5;
chartSeries.Appearance.PointMark.FillStyle.MainColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
chartSeries.Appearance.PointMark.Visible = true;
// Define chart series
ChartSeries chartSeries2 = new ChartSeries();
chartSeries2.Appearance.LabelAppearance.Visible = false;
chartSeries2.Name = "GNP";
chartSeries2.Type = ChartSeriesType.Line;
chartSeries2.Appearance.LineSeriesAppearance.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
// Define the items in the series
chartSeries2.AddItem(2);
chartSeries2.AddItem(3);
chartSeries2.AddItem(3.5);
chartSeries2.AddItem(4);
chartSeries2.AddItem(4.5);
// visually enhance the data points
chartSeries2.Appearance.PointMark.Dimensions.AutoSize = false;
chartSeries2.Appearance.PointMark.Dimensions.Width = 5;
chartSeries2.Appearance.PointMark.Dimensions.Height = 5;
chartSeries2.Appearance.PointMark.FillStyle.MainColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
chartSeries2.Appearance.PointMark.Visible = true;
// set the plot area gradient background fill
radChart.PlotArea.Appearance.FillStyle.FillType = Telerik.Charting.Styles.FillType.Gradient;
radChart.PlotArea.Appearance.FillStyle.MainColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(65, 201, 254);
radChart.PlotArea.Appearance.FillStyle.SecondColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 107, 186);
// Set text and line for X axis
radChart.PlotArea.XAxis.AxisLabel.TextBlock.Text = "Years";
radChart.PlotArea.XAxis.AxisLabel.TextBlock.Appearance.TextProperties.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
radChart.PlotArea.XAxis.Appearance.Width = 3;
radChart.PlotArea.XAxis.Appearance.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
// Set text and line for Y axis
radChart.PlotArea.YAxis.AxisLabel.TextBlock.Text = "%";
radChart.PlotArea.YAxis.AxisLabel.TextBlock.Appearance.TextProperties.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
radChart.PlotArea.YAxis.Appearance.Width = 3;
radChart.PlotArea.YAxis.Appearance.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
// Add the series to the chart, chart to page.radChart.Series.Add(chartSeries);radChart.Series.Add(chartSeries2);this.Page.Controls.Add(radChart)
```

Hope this help..